# Clear specific input fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear certain fields in my form.

I have used the following jQuery code, but they do not work for me:

**My HTML**

```
<section id="clear-section" class="clear-section">
    <a id="clear-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Clear</a>
</section>
```

**jQuery Code 1**

```
let clearLink = $("#clear-link");
clearLink.on("click", function () {
  $("#calc-form-section-1")
    .find('input[type="text"],input[type="number"]')
    .each(function () {
      $(this).val("");
    });
  });
```

**jQuery Code 2**

```
clearLink.on("click", function () {
    let fieldsArray = [
      totalHomeSqftInput,
      calcRoofSqftInput,
      annualKwInput,
      calcKwInput,
      systemSizeInput,
      roofCompInput,
      pwrWallBattInput,
      totalCostInput,
      roofPriceBeforeItc,
      estTotalBeforeItc,
      estItc,
      pwrWallPriceBeforeItc,
    ];
    
    $.forEach(fieldsArray, function () {
      $(this).trigger("reset");
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are the values of `fieldsArray` supposed to be jQuery objects, native DOM elements, or strings? In any case, for Code Section 2, try `$.forEach(fieldsArray, function (e) { $(e).trigger("reset"); });` For Code Section 1, try changing `$(this).val("");` to `this.val("");`

Comment: Those values are supposed to be variables I created that's not shown in this example. They are input field ids to be exact. For instance, for totalHomeSqftInput it is the following: `let totalHomeSqftInput = $("#total-home-sqft-input");`. Thanks! I will try what you recommended.

Comment: Your HTML has no `input` elements. What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, I tried the `$.forEach(fieldsArray, function (e) { $(e).trigger("reset"); });` and it gave an error of: **Uncaught TypeError: $.forEach is not a function**

Comment: it's `each` https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Have you verified that values like `totalHomeSqftInput` have been set properly, and are visible within your callback? It would be helpful if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72579898/edit) to include the relevant HTML so we could see a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, not small pieces of the whole picture.

Comment: *All* your code is often difficult to read through and understand. We just need the smallest sample that is enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: VSCode isn't even showing a .each loop method, it's only giving me a .foreach loop method.

Comment: `.each()` is a [jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/each/), as mentioned above by @LeeTaylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to label the input elements that you wish to clear with a `data-clear` attribute. You can use a selector to search for these input values and clear them using an [each](https://api.jquery.com/each) call.

See demo:

```js
$("#clear-link").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#calc-form-section-1 input[data-clear='true']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="clear-section" class="clear-section">
  <form id="calc-form-section-1">

    <input type="text" data-clear="true" id="totalHomeSqftInput" value="abc" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-clear="true" id="calcRoofSqftInput" value="abc" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-clear="true" id="annualKwInput" value="abc" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-clear="true" id="calcKwInput" value="abc" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-clear="true" id="systemSizeInput" value="abc" /><br />

    <input type="text" id="other" value="abc" /><br />

    <a id="clear-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Clear</a>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Similar: give each field you want to reset a class, eg `<input class='can-clear`>` then `$("input.can-clear")....`